# MP4 files not playing smoothly on windows azure media services

Tags: azure

I have a 3-months trial subscription and I am planning to use azure media services to host my video content. For testing ,  Here's what I am doing

1) From long tail video site, I downloaded an MP4 video url which is playing very well on longtail site.

Here's the player link where you can see how well its playing in browser using that player.

www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/wizard/

The video url from where I downloaded video is

http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-kNspJqnJ.mp4

2) After download, I rename this video and upload it to media services using Portal's upload function. Then I encoded it to HTML5 video and then I published it. After publishing , I got this url

https://quanqamedia.blob.core.windows.net/asset-b58375e6-15d2-46f4-b40f-8163d6d27797/longtail.mp4?st=2013-02-27T12%3A00%3A45Z&se=2015-02-27T12%3A00%3A45Z&sr=c&si=d84c6326-9cdf-43dc-9d4c-20ca02893719&sig=YbpxZdLsMiLakLc22GbJqDqpk4i7Hen7AQIRZy5xvQg%3D

But when I use this url for some player or open it in chrome directly, it plays very slow and strangely.

Can anybody guide me in right direction ? What I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're new to the SO-Community, so I can't post this as a comment:

I accessed both videos with Chrome and VLC. The one hosted in WAMS is neither slow nor strange. The quality is slightly better on the original video - but this is due to the re-encoding...